# Best pratice to upload a digitized document?

Tags: upload

our website will provide a variety of forms where users will need to upload documents.

User surveys have shown that many users have problems digitizing and uploading paper documents.
For example, very few users have a scanner.

One scenario is: The user fills out the form on his desktop computer.
The user photographs the document with his smartphone and sends it to himself by e-mail.
On the desktop PC, the user opens the e-mail and downloads the image.
Finally, the user uploads the image in the form.

do you know best practices how it can be simplified for users with a desktop pc?

an idea for users with desktop pc:
In the form next to the upload field, a personalized link and a qr-code are also offered. If the user opens this link with his smartphone, he can take a picture and upload the file.
as soon as the file is uploaded, the uploaded file is displayed in the form on the desktop pc.
The user can continue to fill out and send the form on his desktop pc.

Answer (score 1):

I would be careful with QR code usage in the West, which has completely died off. Asia has adapted QR codes for almost everything, but not the West. I wouldn't be surprised if users wouldn't know how to scan a QR code. Otherwise your idea seems seamless enough.

Since document uploading will always involve the digitalizing a physical document and uploading to the form, there aren't many ways to simplify this process.

One idea is separating the upload document phase from the rest of the process. This way you can first capture most of the information through the form, leaving the document uploading as a separate step and detaching its burdensome nature from the form step.

Depending on your audience, you might want to offer additional choices for users to provide documents. For example, by providing physical mail or FAX options for older audiences. It might incur more burden on your internal operations, but in exchange for a better customer service.

Separating document uploading also gives you more space for extra services, such as instructions on how upload documents.